# Wordpress cron not getting executed when called by external service (but ok from browser)

Tags: wp-cron, cron

I'm trying to set up an external cron service to run cron in my WP site.

I have disabled WP's own cron using `define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);` in wp-config.php.

As for the URL to call from the external cron service, I've tried with:

https://example.com/wp-cron.php
https://example.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron

But cron isn't executed (I have a custom conr job set up to test this). I've tried several services, they all return HTTP code 200 **so the calls to wp-cron.php are working**, but looks like the hooks associated to cron aren't.

I've installed a plugin (WP Control) to check all the active cron jobs and all other actions aren't getting called either when using the external service.

However, **if I manually call** https://example.com/wp-cron.php by navigating to it from an internet browser, then cron **gets executed fine**.

I must be missing something here but can't figure out what it is, any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT:

Forgot to mention that the external service calls the cron URLs every minute, and the cron job I have set up for testing as well. But all the other cron jobs that run at different intervals have issues when calling cron from external service.

Comment: I'd try `curl -D - https://example.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron` from the shell on the server to see the headers returned and check you're getting 200 OK and not something else. Also look in the cron user's mailbox for any output, and the server error log (or WordPress debug log if set up) just in case something is going wrong.

Comment: @Rup the calls to WP's cron return 200 Ok. There are no server errors, everything works fine if I call the cron URL manually. It just doesn't work if it's called automatically via a service.

Comment: WordPress doesn't know if the request is coming from the service though. I asked you to check the return code in case you were getting a redirect e.g. because you'd got the URL slightly wrong, which your browser would handle fine but curl might not, and to check that there's no server or plugin filter that is dropping curl requests and only allowing looks-like-a-real-browser requests.

Comment: If the requests are all 200 OK, and you see the requests from the service in the access logs, and there are no errors in the logs or in the service, I think you're going to have to put logging trace in wp-cron() to verify that it's really being run by the service and what cron jobs it thinks are outstanding at the point it's called.

Comment: @Rup ok that's a good idea (logging trace in wp-cron), I'll try that. You mention that maybe I got the URL slightly wrong? What would be the correct one? About checking with curl, the thing is that there's not shell access with this hosting account unfortunately :(. But I can try from a different server and see what happens.

Comment: Wrong URL: things like http:// instead of https://, or www vs not-www, which would cause the server to issue a redirect, which you'd then see instead of the 200. (And if you used a desktop browser it would follow the redirect; if you're using some other tool it might not.) It'd be more useful to check on the host that's running the service but you should be able to curl from your PC / laptop too - even Windows ships curl nowadays. But I'm still not sure what could be going wrong.

Comment: @Rup ah gotcha, thank you for the clarification, I checked and the URL is fine, so yeah I'm not sure what might be going on, it's like programmatic external requests are getting blocked.